# How to lane against AP Mid LeBlanc

Tags: league-of-legends

My play-style is a ranged counter-attack, and my Mid Lane Champs matches my play-style. However, I find it hard to lane against mid-lane assassins, specifically LeBlanc.

How do I effectively lane against LeBlanc using each and one of these champs?

Here are my usual Mid-Lane Champs:

1. Morgana
2. Veigar
3. Zilean
4. Zyra

For those who are thinking if I use support as a primary role, the answer is yes. However I find it hard to shift from support to AP mid, some good tips would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Honestly. I've tried. You can't. There is no counter play on Leblanc. I just ban her if going mid.

Comment: So you mean that I should change my playstyle to agressive offensive? I will try to look on that suggestion.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Well for starters you havent picked the strongest midlaners. But ill try to give some tacs etc for your picked champions and some other suggestions

1. Morgana: Go cry. This lane is a mess. The massive CD on your shield vs her low CD spells is practically useless. You can block one burst but if you don't kill her afterwards you are dead. Your binding & soil will practically never hit unless you predict the dash. She is very mobile. Especially after lvl 6. Same for your ult. She can just dash out of its range.
2. Veigar: You actually stand quite a chance as Veigar. Once you get lvl 6 your kill potential is higher then hers I think. Lane safely. Use Q to poke her instead of stacking Q. And when she dashes. Place the "Event Horizon" on the dash marker and launch the meteor. With this tactic you can shut her down pretty easy if she plays a little reckless.
3. Zilean: Your bomb range is higher the her spells and she has no real counter to them as well. I've played this lane last week. You can negate her burst completely with your ult. The main thing in lane is keep up with cs and exp. Also build mana sustain early. So that you can keep spamming rewind for extremely low cd on chrososhift.
4. Zyra: Zyra is actually pretty tricky. Although some similarities with Morgana, your bind goes through minions. But she can still dash out of both your bind & ult with little effort. So if you want kills. Roam.

Like all mid lanes. If you feel unsafe. Play secure. And don't die. After lvl 6 start roaming and make sure you always know where the other mid laner is. Leblanc is a great roamer so be careful

Good Counters to Leblanc:

1. Syndra: Her long range poke and stun are amazing and have a fast travelling time. Although the stun can be tricky to aim. At lvl 6, place as many balls as possible, stun & ult & ignite will kill her
2. Annie: My little pyromaniac <3 although pre-6 it's hard to play vs Leblanc you can easily farm under turret with your Q. Annie her spells are all point and click and there is little room for her to dodge your stun charged "Tibbers". For firstblood. Get stun, flash in, R > W> Q + ignite and she is dead. Annie her burst is amazing at lvl 6.

If you need anymore help & tips just comment.

Comment: Hehe sorry for the sometimes oddly written text, made it while walking to school

Comment: This answer showed that I lacked confidence in my skills. Thanks for the tips, especially Zilean and Veigar. Anyway, I don't use flash, so I can't take the Annie suggestion.

Comment: You don't? Why not? And which summoner spells do you use then?

Comment: Zilean might work, not convinced about veigar. In my experience if you aim skill shots at the launch platform she just stays at short range and punches you in the face while your cooldowns were wasted.

Comment: Even zilean is going to struggle as well, her ult/burst cooldown is lower than his ult cooldown unless you're really really spamming chronoshift.

Comment: in my experience not actually, Here most lb dash in, Q + Chain you and go back immediately. For zilean thats why i said you have to start with mana sustain to spam rewind for the 10s CD reduction. You might not win, but you wont lose either

Comment: @Taacoo I use Ghost instead of Flash. And they all hate me for that. I got used to it, since I primarily play as a support, support of all types (except annie).

Comment: @ChinoCarlo Interesting, any reason for going ghost instead of flash? I only see it on top laners like Nasus & Jax. Combined with Teleport

Comment: @Taacoo Ghost is a better gap closer if you're planning to do it on an open area. While Flash is a better gap closer in places where there are terrain blockages. So, I get a faster cooldown with that.

Comment: @ChinoCarlo Honestly I've seen Flash + Ghost before on annie. Perhaps try that?

Comment: @Haidro &ChinoCarlo i always use ghost as a tool to stick to targets(or flee) While flash is an amazing surprise engage tool. While ghost might work i suggest you use flash if you play mid. Especially as mid lane since you can escape ganks & threating cc better better with flash then ghost.

Comment: @Haidro Yes, I may do Flash + Ghost on Annie. But unfortunately I can't do Annie due to the short range. Anyway, I'll try learning those kind of champs. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: @Taacoo Yes, I'll also take your suggestion of crying if I used Morgana vs Leblanc.

Comment: Are you on euw? Perhaps i can be of small help ingame?

Comment: @Taacoo I'm playing on a completely different server, with completely different people. I'm playing here in the Philippines

Comment: @Taacoo Yeah most LeBlanc jump in then straight back out. When I started aiming skill shots at the launch platform though they just started staying, attaching tether and not going back every time. So I aim skill shots at launch platform I end up with them punching me in the face. I aim them locally and normally they have time to go back to platform... it's really a lose-lose situation. I'm going to have to try Zilean though. Sounds like it might work.

Comment: @Tim B remember with zilean its more of a not losing lane then winning. Delay her power spike as long as possible and keep her in lane

Comment: Also note, LeBlanc derives a lot of kill potential from her ult and skill combos. Her very early game is weak and unstable as she doesn't either doesn't have the CC, dash, or burst (depending on which skill she chooses) that makes her so threatening. If you can gimp her early with strong harass and ganks, the rest of the game will be an uphill battle for her.

Comment: Honestly, I don't see how morgana is being bullied there. She won't kill LB but she should get ahead in farm.
once lvl 5, she can push like crazy, and except if lb uses his w on the creeps, he will have to farm under tower.
LB has a really weak wave clearance. So use it against him. Everytime he goes after you, he will more or less lose 6 CS. hummm not sure it's worth...
And you can roam ...

Answer (score 3):

To be able to counter champions efficiently, you need a way bigger pool of champions you can play to pick from, 4 is just not enough. That's good at first if you just started to learn midlane, but it won't be enough in the long run. Moreover as you only have one playstyle, being versatile is even more difficult.

If you want to counter a champion your pick is the priority (considering you can actually play it ^^, never pick a champ just because it's a counter, you need to know him for it to work). Champions like Galio (non burstable) or Fizz (can stick to her at all times) are the best for this match-up. But if you really want a "ranged counter-attack" champion, Syndra is the one to take. She is a really strong pick against Leblanc for several reasons :

- You have a lot of a quick harass to keep-up with her
- As soon as you are 6, it's a burst race but your full combo outdamages her (stun(Q+E) + slow(W) + ult(R) + ignite)
- A lot of champions have a hard time finishing her because of her strong decoy/invisibility passive, but with Syndra just make sure to ult + ignite right before it triggers and it will kill her anyways.

Comment: I might as well re-learn Syndra now.

Answer (score 0):

What's lacking in the answers IMO is HOW to play against a Leblanc not as a specific champion, but in general.

Leblanc has a very high damage output, but is probably one of the squishiest champ in the game. After the removal of the silence on her Q-proc laning against Leblanc has become much easier - You can now efficiently trade back once she has used her combo. But not only that, after her Q+W (in lane) you typically have a 15 second window to exploit the hell out of her cooldown (W CD: 18/16/14/12/10).

The important thing to do against a Leblanc is to push when she has CDs! Even if she just took you down to 50% with one Q+W, don't be scared - Retaliate! The one thing you have to be obs for is a Q+E as her Q has a low cd. She also has terrible waveclear unless she is going to be using W on minions (which doesn't even clear the wave early and would put her at great disadvantage when it comes to trading). Therefore when you have the upper hand you can and should push her to the turret and make her focus on lasthitting as you poke her.

Additional Notes:

Jungler:
If you can easily communicate with the jungler, be it that you're a fast typer or using voice-chat, you should inform him/her whether or not the Leblanc is being aggressive with her W. The jungler should stand in a bush and wait for her to use Distortion (W) and then go in towards the pop-back for the gank. If you are duoQing with a jungler, you might consider choosing a champion with hard cc mid as to organize your ganks.

Champions:
I've seen a lot of players going **Galio** recently as you can negate her combo pretty well with your shield (W) and stacking MR is a natural thing on him.

**Syndra** counters Leblanc for various reasons, most mentioned above. But IMO the most important being that **she can actually stop her midair with her E (when she W)**, like Galio, completey negating and often with a follow up stun to burst her down.

Zed and Yasuo can both dodge Q+W by using their own dashes if you're good at predicting them. Zed can also negate a lot of damage with his ulti. 
Zed (Faker) vs. Leblanc:

Runes: 
Could be an idea to have your own runepage where you replace yellows with hp instead of armor and flat mr blues instead of scaling.

Answer (score 0):

Most leblancs take flask + 2 pots now adays against any match up to increase her sustain since her wave clear is almost absolute trash . But she does have damage . She can set a huge amount of chunk with a q + w combo . Know this , Her cooldown for her distorition (W) is so high . You can abuse that , the best way to not get combo'd is to poke her first . But it also depends on the match up , You can't play those type of mids against her , but they are not even in the meta. Veigar can however always always outscale her but you should know , right after you see the animation of leblac throwing a q on you , as veigar , throw your e on yourself and her w is canceld . The animation is stunned and you take no damage from w + q proc. She can't take damage back . That's why shes very easy to trade against her if you play it smart . 
1. PLay agrresive , She will abuse the w and her passive to get through escapes . 
2. Out cs her . Lb wave clear is bad because if she is forced to use w or w+r to wave clear , you have 10 seconds to kill her , poke her and or make her use her passive. 
3. Ganks. Bait her poke the q+w and you can easily gank her if shes not 6.

Kill the lane doesn't mean you have to kill the champ , just outsmart her . If you know what she's ganna do , Why not stop it ?

Answer (score 0):

When a LeBlanc sees an opening, they will immediately Q W E or Q R E W for hard poke and all ins, respectively. (Hope!) Her other spells might be on cooldown, so when you take her Q, stand far behind your minons and use your ranged spells to take CS. For example, when I AP Ezreal mid and a LeBlanc Q's me, I immediately blink right when she dashes and unleash full combo hell. But if you picked an immobile caster, you're dead. End of story.

Moral? PICK AP EZ VS LEBLANC